# Problem with sending email

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

The send method of SMTP is always throwing an exception. The message is : **Failure sending mail**

Here is my code:

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
mm.To.Add("Yuvraj.dhot@xxxxx.co.in");

mm.From = new MailAddress("Kumar.Chaudhari@xxxxx.co.in");
mm.Subject = "Ant Subject";
mm.Body = "Body Cha MEssag here ";

SmtpClient ss = new SmtpClient("localhost");

ss.EnableSsl = false;

try
{
    **ss.Send(mm);**
    Result.Text = "Message Sent";
    Result.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
}
catch (SmtpException ex)
{
    Result.Text = "Message Not Sent : \n\n " + ex.Message;
    Result.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

I also tried using

```
ss.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
```

Now it doesn't throw any exception, it executes fine but receiver does not receive any mail in his inbox.

How can I fix this?

Edit - This is the stack trace im getting

```
    Message=Failure sending mail. Source=System StackTrace: at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send
(MailMessage message) at WebApplication1._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Emcure-
Kumar\Work\Not in Use\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Default.aspx.cs:line 30 InnerException: 
System.Net.WebException Message=Unable to connect to the remote server Source=System StackTrace: –
    at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async,
 IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6, Int32 timeout) at 
System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, 
GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, 
GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, 
GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
    at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port) at 
System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port) at 
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) 
InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException Message=No connection could be made because the 
target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:25 Source=System ErrorCode=10061 NativeErrorCode=10061
```

Comment: Do you have a mail service running on your local machine?

Comment: yes i did start ir before excuting it

Comment: @O.D he has, it is "Failure sending mail".

Comment: Can you post the full details (type and *all* properties including stack trace and innerException's type and *all* properties if it is not null), not just the message.

Answer (score 2):

Your execption should contain more info than "Failure sending mail"

For debugging look at this link for details on the Exeptions thrown by SmtpClient.Send Method - > [SmtpClient.Send Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc.aspx)

This code works with "smtp.google.com"

```
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
        mm.From = new MailAddress("xx");
        mm.To.Add("xx");
        mm.Subject = "Ant Subject"; 
        mm.Body = "Body Cha MEssag here ";

        SmtpClient ss = new SmtpClient();
        ss.Host="smtp.gmail.com";
        ss.Port = 587;
        ss.EnableSsl = true;

        ss.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xx", "xx");
        try 
        { 
            ss.Send(mm); 
            Label1.Text = "Message Sent";
            Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green; 
        }
        catch (SmtpException ex) 
        { 
            Label1.Text = "Message Not Sent : \n\n " + ex.Message;
            Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
```

Google requires SSL enabled and port 587 to be the outgoing port. You need a google account as well for credentials.

Nothing wrong with your code - it's most likely your server or firewall

Comment: Message=Failure sending mail.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
       at WebApplication1._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Emcure-Kumar\Work\Not in Use\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Default.aspx.cs:line 30
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       Message=Unable to connect to the remote server
       Source=System
       StackTrace:

Comment: at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6, Int32 timeout)
            at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
            at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
            at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)

Comment: at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
            at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
            at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
            at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
       InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
            Message=No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:25
            Source=System
            ErrorCode=10061
            NativeErrorCode=10061

Comment: This is The Exception what i am getting

Comment: @Kumar "Unable to connect to the remote server" Did you try the same using another mail server like gmail? do you get the same error?

Comment: also - you might want to check that your firewall permits traffick on port 25

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this in your web.config first:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <!-- Use this setting for development
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="mail.mydomain.com" port="25" />
      </smtp>
      -->
      <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\Tmp"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

This will copy all files into C:\Tmp. 
You can just instantiate the class like this:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
```

And the change the configuration in your web.config afterwards. Give it a try an let us know if this helps.

Comment: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException was caught
  Message=Failure sending mail.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
       at WebApplication1._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Emcure-Kumar\Work\Not in Use\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Default.aspx.cs:line 30
  InnerException: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
       Message=Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Tmp\cd7da094-97a5-4057-af9d-e17a842b89c4.eml'.

Comment: It says:
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException Message=Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Tmp\
So, somethings wrong with c:\tmp. Does IIS have write access to it?

Answer (score 1):

I Had the same problem, and was my proxy, i dont know really, because my ie have a proxy with a good configuration, and i read that a C# app get the configuration of the OS proxy. I just change my conecction to some that dont have Proxy and run very well. All solution, 1st, 2nd and 3th. Maybe is something like proxy or firewall, or try your program in other PC to confirm. I hope that help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

    try
    {
       // System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(txt_name.Text, txt_to.Text);


        smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";


        smtpClient.Port = 25;

       // msg.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("xyz@gmail.com");

      message.From = fromAddress;

        message.To.Add("xyz111@gmail.com");


        message.Body = txt_des.Text;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

        System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();

        NetworkCred.UserName = "xyz@gmail.com";

        NetworkCred.Password = "xtz";

        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        smtpClient.Credentials = NetworkCred; 


        smtpClient.Send(message);

        lblStatus.Text = "Email successfully sent.";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblStatus.Text = "Send Email Failed." + ex.Message;
    }
```